# Deploy ASP.NET MVC 4 to Staging and Eventually Windows Azure

Tags: iis, azure, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 app. This will needs to be deployed to an internal IIS server, which is a Windows Server 2008 machine, for testing. Eventually, we will deploy the app to Windows Azure as a Web Role. From my understanding, there is a way to have a "private" cloud on Windows Server 2008.

What is the recommended way to deploy an ASP.NET MVC 4 app to a "private cloud"? Please bear in mind that this app will eventually go to the public version of Windows Azure.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you eventually want to deploy on Azure, I would strongly recommend that you test on Azure.  If this is a commercial project that you're working with and you want to do one month's testing that will cost you approximately $160 for two instances (you really do need to test with two instances).  Compare that to the hourly rate of whoever has to setup and support the server and you're probably already ahead.

You can run your site on premise with IIS, SQL and even AppFabric caching (Velocity) and all of these are similar to what you get in Azure, but not the same.  Windows Azure SQL DB (WASD) in particular has different restrictions to and a different performance profile than an on premise SQL Server DB.  If you want to use Azure Storage, there is no on premise version of this.

Answer (score 0):

I would get a Windows Azure VM (or doesn't matter, it can be an server on premises) and deploy through web deploy.

Here is a great blog post on how to get a VM up and running with web deploy with only one script:

[Script Out Everything - Initialize Your Windows Azure VM for Your Web Server with IIS, Web Deploy and Other Stuff](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/script-out-everything-initialize-your-windows-azure-vm-for-your-web-server-with-iis-web-deploy-and-other-stuff)

I used Windows Server 2012 there and PowerShell 3.0. So, there might be a few things that are not available in Windows Server 2008 R2. However, I heard that PowerShell 3.0 is now available for down level OSes. If that's true, I would also recommend you to get it installed at the first place because it has new capabilities.